# Which method can export labelled tiles/patches from original image?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, medical, medical-imaging

My co-operator has a set of histopathology slide images. Yet they do not have labeling experience. Usually for ML training, such data needs to export as labelled (in file name) patches/tiles. Are there any existed method that can allow the co-operator just draw the ROI (positive) region and easily export the positive and negative patches/tiles?